# integrating docker with pbs pro

Tags: docker, scheduler, pbs

I am following this guide to integrating docker with pbs pro:
http://www.pbsworks.com/ResLibDownload.aspx?file_id2=7190&from_page=ResourceLibrary.aspx%3Fkeywords%3DPBS%2BProfessional%2Bwith%2BDocker%2BIntegration

on the ninth steps it says :,
Compile the pbs_container C code:
gcc pbs_container.c -o pbs_container -I /pbspro/src/include/ -L/opt/pbs/lib -lpbs -lcrypto -
lpthread

do you guys know where is pbs_container.c code ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This file can be only found in the commercial release of PBS Pro.
[Discussion 1](http://community.pbspro.org/t/cant-find-pbs-container-c-on-docker-integration/1261)
[Discussion 2](http://community.pbspro.org/t/did-anyone-tried-to-run-docker-containers-using-pbs/646/4)